# Vue - How to use a dynamic ref with composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

I am using the composition API in Vue 3 and want to define a ref to a component.
Usually that would be done by adding `ref="name"` to the template and then defining a ref with the same name: `const name = ref(null)`.
The problem is I want to use dynamic ref names.
Any idea how to solve this?

In the options API I could do something like this:
`:ref="`name${x}`"` and then access it in the code like this: `this.$refs[`name${x}`]`.
But with the composition API I don't have access to $refs.
Is there a way to do this without using a function inside the template ref?

Comment: Are you using a loop? Please show the real use case

Comment: Maybe [function ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs) can help you.

Answer (score 3):

The `:ref` prop accepts a function (see [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs)), which you can use to assign it to the variable you want:

```html
<script setup>
const dynamicRef = ref(null);
</script>

<template>
  <Count :ref="(el) => dynamicRef = el" />
</template>
```

[Vue playground example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the [Refs inside v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) is a better match for what you are trying to achieve.

> Requires Vue v3.2.25 or above

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const list = ref([1, 2, 3])

const itemRefs = ref([])

onMounted(() => {
  alert(itemRefs.value.map(i => i.textContent))
})
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="itemRefs">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

[Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)