Unable to Access Methods from Dynamically Rendered Vue 3 Component Using <component :is="..."> and ref
I'm working on a Vue 3 component where I dynamically render another component using <component :is="...">. The dynamically rendered component has a method (e.g., export()) that I need to call when a button is clicked. However, I’m unable to access this method using ref.
Here’s a simplified version of what I’m trying to achieve:
<template>
  <div>
    <component
      :is="dynamicComponent"
      :ref="dynamicRef"
    />
    <button @click="handleClick">Call Export</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, nextTick } from 'vue'
import MyDynamicComponent from './MyDynamicComponent.vue'

// Define the dynamic component and ref
const dynamicComponent = ref(MyDynamicComponent)
const dynamicRef = ref(null)

// Attempt to call the export method
const handleClick = async () => {
  await nextTick()

  if (dynamicRef.value && typeof dynamicRef.value.export === 'function') {
    dynamicRef.value.export()
  } else {
    console.warn('Failed to call export() on the dynamic component.')
  }
}
</script>

The problem is that when I try to call the export() method using dynamicRef.value, it is undefined or doesn’t have the method I’m expecting or says that export is not a function.
What I've Tried

Using ref to track the component instance.

Adding nextTick() to ensure the component is fully mounted before attempting to call the method.

Using useTemplateRef


What I’m Looking For

How can I reliably access a method from a dynamically rendered component using <component :is="..."> in Vue 3?

Are there any best practices for interacting with child components rendered this way?

What am I missing or doing incorrectly in my setup?


Anything that may help? thanks in advice!!

Have you tried used defineExpose in the child component? https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup#defineexpose
Also I just tried to find some other solutions and this might be a direction you can try. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75131724/11423857

Could it be because you have :ref instead of just ref? Corrected: 

I wrote this code into my sample project and it worked. and I hope your problem is fixed by this solution
myChildComponent:
<template>
  <div>
    Child Component Content
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { provide } from 'vue';

const exportData = () => {
  console.log("this is exporting data...");
};

provide('exportData', exportData);
</script>

page :
<template>
    <div>
      <component :is="dynamicComponent" />
      <button @click="callExport">Call Export</button>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  import { ref, inject } from 'vue';
  import MyDynamicComponent from '../components/MyDynamicComponent.vue';
  
  const dynamicComponent = ref(MyDynamicComponent);
  const exportData = inject('exportData', () => {
    console.warn('exportData not available!');
  });
  
  function callExport() {
    if (exportData) {
      exportData();
    }
  }
  </script>

